How to handle Grpc client channel reconnect scenarios in Java
I am using GRPC java 1.50 to handle Grpc communication among different components and using consul as service discovery.
On client side, I am caching ManagedChannel in ConcurrentHashMap for each service as I wish to reuse the same channel.
I am facing two issues:
a) When Grpc Server is restarted or Grpc server is moved to another host, I have no way of knowing when the channel is closed etc.
On trying below approaches :
private final ConcurrentMap<String, ManagedChannel> channels;


ManagedChannelBuilder managedChannelBuilder = ManagedChannelBuilder
                    .forTarget(target)
                    .usePlaintext();
final ManagedChannel channel = managedChannelBuilder
                .build();
                
monitorChannelState(channel, service);
 
private void monitorChannelState(ManagedChannel channel, String service) {
    channel.notifyWhenStateChanged(ConnectivityState.TRANSIENT_FAILURE, () -> {
        logger.warn("Channel is in TRANSIENT_FAILURE state for [service={}]. Attempting to reconnect...", service);
        close(service);
        create(service);
    });

    channel.notifyWhenStateChanged(ConnectivityState.IDLE, () -> {
        logger.info("Channel is in IDLE state for [service={}]. Requesting connection...", service);
        channel.getState(true); // Request connection
    });
}

void close(final String service) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(service)) {
        ManagedChannel removedChannel = channels.remove(service);
        if (removedChannel != null) {
            logger.info("Closing down Channel [service={}]", service);
           removedChannel.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
}

Scanario 1:
On monitoring for channel.notifyWhenStateChanged(ConnectivityState.SHUTDOWN), it tries to recreate channel for every call, which is not optimised solution.
Scenario 2:
On monitoring for channel.notifyWhenStateChanged(ConnectivityState.TRANSIENT_FAILURE), it ends up in connect loop, Even adding exponential reconnect strategies, IT is same loop.
My query is that how to recreate channel when Grpc server is restarted or moved to another machine

"When Grpc Server is restarted or Grpc server is moved to another host" should have no impact on whether the channel is "shutdown." The name resolver should give new addresses and the channel will reconnect on its own.

Please read the documentation for notifyWhenStateChanged(). You pass the current state the the method, not the desired state.
